# 'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, sed, windows-10, yarnpkg, gnuwin32

I'm working with a JavaScript app it's running by `yarn`. I found issue when I run `yarn run dev`. It's showing below error.

```
yarn run v1.21.1
$ yarn fixlitepicker && rm -rf .cache/ dist/
$ sed -i 's/# sourceMappingURL/ sourceMappingURL/g' node_modules/litepicker/dist/js/main.js
'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I know it's come from `package.json` scripts.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel src/index.html",
    "build": "yarn install && yarn fixlitepicker && parcel build src/index.html",
    "prebuild": "rm -rf dist",
    "predev": "yarn fixlitepicker && rm -rf .cache/ dist/",
    "fixlitepicker": "sed -i 's/# sourceMappingURL/ sourceMappingURL/g' node_modules/litepicker/dist/js/main.js"
  },
```

I already download [SED](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) and install it. Install location `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32`. But it's not working. I seen same issue. I don't understand how to fix this issue.

**System**

**OS**: `Windows 10 Pro`.
**OS Version**: `1909`.
**OS System Type**: `64-bit operating system, x64-based processor`.

[image]

Comment: Clearly the script was written for Unix-like platforms. Can you get rid of Windows here? (You'll thank me later.)

Comment: Try to run the yarn command from a GNU a shell terminal environment (v.gr. bash) rather than from a Windows command line.

Comment: there are 22 other Q/A's here when I search the exact text of your Subject Line. AND if if remove `sed is` from that search, there are 6000+ other Q/As dealing with this subject. Did you review these messages to help solve your problem?  Please do and Good luck.

Comment: Changing the agent from 'windows-latest' to 'ubuntu-latest' solved the issue. Thanks to @tripleee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set the HOME directory as mentioned in here, http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/install.html

If it doesn't fix, install http://cygwin.com/ and give a try

Comment: Thanks for your ans. **Cygwin** terminal work but **GnuWin32** have error.

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded and installed ‘sed’ from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) but it’s just not on your path.
You need to run in a terminal where `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32` is added to PATH. You might also benefit from installing ‘which’ and then you can have a sanity check with `which sed`

Comment: `which` is not standard either; anyway, Windows already has `whereis` with basically the same functionality.